# Symfony FOSJsRoutingBundle how to set/detect host?

Tags: javascript, symfony, routes

I want to generate absolute url using the **FOSJsRoutingBundle** for **Symfony**. This is basically what I'm doing:

```
Routing.generate("route_name", {}, true);
```

It result in an url like `http://localhost/my/route`. The host is `localhost`, no matter the environment.

How am I supposed to deal with it if I want the path to reflect the current configuration?

I couldn't find anything about it in the docs and no method to explicitly define the `host`'s property of `Routing`.

Comment: Take a deep look at this issue. The same problem with yours has already been solved.
[FosJsRoutingBundle-1](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/issues/57)
[FosJsRoutingBundle-2](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/issues/72)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate absolute urls based on the current environment, make sure your FOSJsRoutingBundle is setup properly by following the docs: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Also, don't forget to include the script below (after the js files that contain the routes and the `Routing` object).

```
 <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

This is actually a little piece of javascript that is going to set `Routing`'s config dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The host is defined in your routes.
So if you want something else than *localhost* add the host to your route.

```
route_name:
  pattern: /my/route
  defaults:
    _controller: MyBundle:Default:index
  options:
    expose: true
  schemes:  [https]
  host: vhost.local
```

Then you will get: https://vhost.local/my/route
with:

```
Routing.generate("route_name", {}, true);
```

If you want to change the index page add this in your config

```
fos_js_routing:
   request_context_base_url: /app_dev.php
```

Additional to the host stuff from above this will render:
https://vhost.local/app_dev.php/my/route

Comment: I can't "hard code" the host as the domain changes depending on the user's language. So the url could look like `http://en.site.com/` or `http://ch.site.com/` and so on.

Comment: you could try: host: %locale%.%my_host_from_parameters%